# Web Scraping (vb.net) I can't choose I need the information that is after the alt="estados unidos", could you tell me what I'm doing wrong

Tags: vb.net

`Web Scraping` (vb.net) I can't choose the `country`, could you tell me what I'm doing wrong

```
Dim NAVEGADOR As New WebBrowser 
  
Private Sub ButtonINICIAR_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonINICIAR.Click

        NAVEGADOR.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True 'POR SI HAY ERRORES DE SCRIPT
        NAVEGADOR.Navigate("https://www.filmaffinity.com/es/film794030.html") 'VAMOS A LA WEB
End Sub
```

This is my code :

```
 Public Sub DIVISAS()

    For Each ETIQUETA As HtmlElement In NAVEGADOR.Document.GetElementsByTagName("dd")
        If ETIQUETA.TagName = "dd" Then
            If ETIQUETA.GetAttribute("alt") = "dd" Then
                TextBox1.Text += ETIQUETA.InnerText
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This is the page tag

```
<dd><span id="country-img"><img class="nflag" src="/imgs/countries2/US.png" alt="Estados Unidos"></span>&nbsp;Estados Unidos</dd>
```

I do not know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: alt isn't an attribute of <dd>

Comment: Take images where class = nflag instead

Comment: I need the information that is after the alt="estados unidos"